# ComputeSignature and Manually generated hash are different

Tags: c#, xml, cryptography, digital-signature, sha256

I am creating a request xml with digital signature. Below is my code.

```
CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription), "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");

        var exportedKeyMaterial = cert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString( /* includePrivateParameters = */ true);
        var key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(new CspParameters(24 /* PROV_RSA_AES */));
        key.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
        key.FromXmlString(exportedKeyMaterial);

        string tokenId = string.Format("X509-{0}", Guid.NewGuid());
        string signatureId = string.Format("SIG-{0}", Guid.NewGuid());
        string tokenRefId = string.Format("STR-{0}", Guid.NewGuid());
        string kiId = string.Format("KI-{0}", Guid.NewGuid());
        string bodyId = string.Format("id-{0}", Guid.NewGuid());

        XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
        ns.AddNamespace("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        ns.AddNamespace("wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
        ns.AddNamespace("wsa", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing");
        ns.AddNamespace("wsu", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");

        XmlElement body = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(@"//soapenv:Body", ns) as XmlElement;
        if (body == null)
            throw new ApplicationException("No body tag found");

        body.SetAttribute("id", bodyId);

        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(body);
        signedXml.Signature.Id = signatureId;
        signedXml.SigningKey = key;
        signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";

        KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
        keyInfo.Id = kiId;

        SecurityTokenReference tokenRef = new SecurityTokenReference();
        tokenRef.ValueType = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3";
        tokenRef.RelativeReference = tokenId;
        tokenRef.Id = tokenRefId;

        // Add Security Token reference
        keyInfo.AddClause(tokenRef);
        signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

        signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigExcC14NTransformUrl;

        XmlDsigExcC14NTransform canMethod = (XmlDsigExcC14NTransform)signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethodObject;
        canMethod.InclusiveNamespacesPrefixList = "soap";

        Reference reference = new Reference();
        reference.Uri = string.Format("#{0}", bodyId);
        reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";

        reference.AddTransform(new Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Xml.XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
        signedXml.AddReference(reference);

        signedXml.ComputeSignature();

XmlElement signedElement = signedXml.GetXml();

 string hash = CalculateDigestOfBody(body);

public string CalculateDigestOfBody(XmlElement xmlDoc)
        {
            SHA256 algo = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] byteHash = algo.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlDoc.OuterXml));
            string hashString = Convert.ToBase64String(byteHash);

            return hashString;
        }
```

This produces the below soap header

```
<Signature Id="SIG-44779d9b-7d39-4c27-877b-a6de1d9365fc" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
        <InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="soap" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
    </CanonicalizationMethod>
    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
    <Reference URI="#id-98b3d734-ee46-49bb-aee8-c151d41defe5">
        <Transforms>
            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
        <DigestValue>..</DigestValue>
    </Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>..</SignatureValue>
```

When I compare the digest value from ComputeSignature and manually calculated hash/digest, they are not equal.

As per my understanding they should be equal as both are calculated on body.

What am I missing here.

Comment: Do you have to use XmlDocument? Namespace handling is *really* easy with LINQ to XML. Btw, would you mind reformatting the output onto multiple lines? It's really hard to read as a single long line. (I'm happy to do it for you if you'd like, but I don't want to do it without your permission.)

Comment: @DaisyShipton I have done the formatting. I can use Linq to XML but again, the main concern is how to make InclusiveNamespaces use a prefix. I don't want to do it programatically by traversing the xml. I think there should be a way to set it in CanonicalizationObject.

Comment: Now we can see the XML, it's clearer what you're asking - but it's not clear to me why. It looks like `InclusiveNamespaces` simply is in a different namespace URI, and I suspect it's *deliberately* in a different namespace URI. Given that this is a framework type that's specifying its namespace, can you give more context about why you think it should be in a the same namespace as Signature? You talk about "ambiguity error" - could you give the *exact* error in the question please?

Comment: The problem is Signature element has defined xmlns with some URI. Now since this namespace is created without any prefix, it will be inherited by all the children and hence the InclusiveNamespaces element will also inherit it. But InclusiveNamespaces itself is creating xmlns with different URI. So, the framework is not able to recognize actually which URI it should accept.

Comment: What do you mean by "not recognize actually which URI it should accept"? All it means is that the InclusiveNamespaces element is in a different namespace URI. There's nothing ambiguous about it - it's just in a different namespace.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I got your point.I was confused due to inheritance. I have edited this question. Can you please have a look and tell me what is wrong with my code. Why the digest value don't match.

Comment: Unfortunately at that point we're beyond my area of expertise. XML namespaces I know a bit about - XML signatures, not so much. Still, I hope the comments have helped you a little bit.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Your comments about XML namespaces helped me solve the problems I was facing in digital signature. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

For those who are interested in the answer:

Never change the body or signed info element once you call ComputeSignature method. Additionally try not to change anything in the children of soap:header manually.

Below are the code that I was doing wrong. Commenting that works perfectly.

```
signedElement.Prefix = "ds";
signedElement.FirstChild.Prefix = "ds";
signedElement.FirstChild.FirstChild.Prefix = "ds";
```

I was adding these line below ComputeSignature. And after that I was trying to calculate the digest manually. So, both the digests can never match.

Any change in the digested input will change the digest.